# Persisting entities state

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a testing application.
There are `Test` (a group of questions), `Question`, `Choice` entities in the app.
Before a user starts a test I need make a snapshot of a current `Test` entities state (with all its associations) in order to prevent influencing of changes made to `Test` entity during the time user passing the test.
I need a way to persist this "snapshot" in DB. What I can imagine for now is to persist this state as an array in one of the fields.
Is there a better ways to do it? Any ideas, please.

**UPDATE**
The main reason for saving the snapshot of a test state is that the client wants view test results with exact questions and choices on the time when user was passing it.

Comment: And what would you do with this snapshot?  Try to roll back changes after the test?

Comment: @Cerad I mostly interested in saving questions state that belongs to a test - in order to the text of questions remains the same (if admin changes the questions during the time user is passing the test or even delete some of them, it might be some weird effects if not to save a state).

Comment: I've added a description of Test entity.

Comment: Okay.  I thought you were talking about testing your application.  I don't think your snapshot is really the way to go.  If the admin wants to changes the test questions then I would just make a complete copy of the entire test and leave the previous one alone.

Comment: @Cerad Yeah I expressed it in really confusing way, sorry. By a complete copy do you mean to copy DB rows? Or somehow serialize the test and store it in that way? Just in case I would add that I'm building a simple test application - a user answers on series of question and in the end gets the result - whether they has passed it or not.

Comment: Well it's not so simple if one of the requirements is to be able to change the test and still see the previous questions.  I am talking about copying the database rows.  Trying to compare serialized data seems like a painful process.

Comment: @Cerad Yeah, they also want view detailed results (with all the questions and choices and given answers) in any period of time in the future. So it makes me store a state of a test (with all the questions and choices) in the beginning of a test. Fortunately I need not lookup through test data but just read it. I looking for the less painful way to store such a state. I think I will apply JsonSerializable to Test, Question and Choice entities and will store they as json in DB. It seems there is no other way. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like you are determines to serialize.  So trust your instincts and go for it.

Comment: @Cerad Sounds fun =)) Actually I don't like the idea to store serialized data, but don't know how to meet requirements another way. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to persist changes set (with timestamp or version order) then calculate the result at the end.
you can use the Symfony [Entity Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html)

Comment: I need just a state, because it will be used in the future (I updated the question for clarification).

Comment: (Not related to this answer.) Re your question about JavaScript coercion (which I felt didn't deserve downvoting at all; *maybe* it was off-topic and should have been closed), answers: http://pastie.org/10508579 Enjoy.